# Delete all information from document but persist it's ObjectId, mongoengine

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine

I need to delete all information but to persist objectId, because it can be referenced to outside my function (so just clear all fields, do not recreate)
I've heard i can do it with update() with no args or something like that.
Of course i can do it manually, but i'm sure there is a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a bunch of batch writes to replace document with one that is empty *e.g.*

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, ReplaceOne

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test

requests = [ReplaceOne(doc, {}) for doc in db.collection.find()]
result = db.collection.bulk_write(requests)
```

Comment: I would prefer mongoengine if possible, btw i changed strategy a little
if anyone is interested you can do something like this:
```foo = MyModel.objects.get(name='needed')  
bar = MyModel.create(id=foo.id)```